# How do you determine if a result in a search query is a post or a page?

Tags: wp-query, search, post-type

I thought this question would be an easy find on the internet… however, it seems no one has ever ran into this issue before.

There's no problem in listing a search query when you enter your search term, **I needed posts and pages to be differentiated in a way**. For example: I'd like results that are posts (articles) to display the author, read time, and post date, but I do not like these metas to appear on results that are pages.

Here's a code:

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $searchArgs = array(
    's' => $s,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'showposts' => -1,
    );
    $searchQuery = new WP_Query( $searchArgs );
    if ( $searchQuery->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<h2>';
    echo 'result: '.search_query();
    echo '</h2>';
    while ( $searchQuery->have_posts() ) : $searchQuery->the_post();
      echo 'link: '.get_the_permalink();
      echo 'Title: '.get_the_title();
      echo 'Post Summary: '.get_the_excerpt();
      $how = ( is_single() ) ? 'this result is a post' : 'your method did not work'; //always return false
      $how = ( is_page() ) ? 'this result is a page' : 'your method did not work'; //always return false.
      echo 'Post Type: '.$how; // <------ How to do?
      //***Problem***: is_single() or is_page() does not work, by the way (both return false).
      //I've crossed-checked that the results are actually either a post or a page.
    endwhile;
    endif;

if ( function_exists('custom_pagination') ) {
      custom_pagination($searchQuery->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
    }
```

So my problem is, is_page() and is_single() does not work within the Search Query I made.

How do you do this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

That will only tell you if it's a Post or a Page.  What if it's a category, tag, archive, or custom post type?  Here's how I'd write that, if you care.

```
function xyz_get_post_type_name() {
    $wp_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID()  );
    switch ($wp_type) {
        case 'post' :
            $type_name = 'Article';
        break;
        case 'page' :
            $type_name = 'Web Page';
        break;
        case 'quote' :
            $type_name = 'Testimonial';
        break;
        case 'post_tag' :
            $type_name = 'Topic';
        break;
        default : 
            $type_name = ucfirst($wp_type);
        break;
    } // END switch
    return $type_name;
} // END xyz_get_post_type_name()
```

Then just echo that function inside your loop wherever you want it.

```
while ( $searchQuery->have_posts() ) : $searchQuery->the_post();
    echo 'Post Type Name: ' . xyz_get_post_type_name();
endwhile;
```

The switch statement would also allow you to give these post types a "pretty" name and default to just their actual name (first letter capitalized).

Answer (score 0):

…Figured it out… 5 minutes later…

```
    $queryIsPost = (get_post_type() === 'post') ? true : false; //the solution
    $queryIsPage = (get_post_type() === 'page') ? true : false; //the solution

    $searchArgs = array(
    's' => $s,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'showposts' => -1,
    );
    $searchQuery = new WP_Query( $searchArgs );
    if ( $searchQuery->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<h2>';
    echo 'result: '.search_query();
    echo '</h2>';
    while ( $searchQuery->have_posts() ) : $searchQuery->the_post();
      echo 'link: '.get_the_permalink();
      echo 'Title: '.get_the_title();
      echo 'Post Summary: '.get_the_excerpt();
      if ($queryIsPost) {
        $thePostType = "Post";
      } elseif ($queryIsPage) {
        $thePostType = "Page";
      } else {
        $thePostType = "Error. Not determined";
      }
      echo 'Post Type: '.$thePostType;

    endwhile;
    endif;
```